# MySQL query finding count from a distinct value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 58k of transaction records in it. I want to bring back only the payment_ref (the client ID) that have 3 declined payments in the date parameter (Usually 1 day). The payment is tried 3 times in a day, and as long as one of them is authorised, I am happy. Its the declined 3 times in a day that I need to chase up. The query I have at the minute is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cp.payment_ref) as ref
              , (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                   FROM client_payments 
                  WHERE status LIKE 'Declined' 
                    AND payment_ref = ref) as declined 
           FROM client_payments as cp 
          WHERE cp.payment_date BETWEEN '2018-05-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-14 23:59:59'
```

But the query is taking ages, the counts are above 3 (the embedded query seems to be searching on the whole table), I have indexes on all the search fields. The table is set out as follows:-

```
name , payment_ref, timestamp          , status
smith, 123        , 2018-05-15 10:12:22, Declined
smith, 123        , 2018-05-15 14:12:22, Declined
smith, 123        , 2018-05-15 19:12:22, Declined
john , 246        , 2018-05-15 10:12:22, Declined
john , 246        , 2018-05-15 14:12:22, Authorised (OK, 2nd payment is auth'd)
jones, 135        , 2018-05-15 10:00:22, Authorised (OK, 1st payment is auth'd)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have indices on payment_date, status and payment_ref? Why use LIKE when you can do =.

Comment: Hint: Use group by on payment_ref, date(timestamp), count(status=declined) and having count(status = declined ) > 2

Comment: Yes there are indices on the date status an ref, I ahve just run it with '=' and same slow running

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no need for a dependent sub query to get the count, you can get it from main query and get rid of distinct use aggregation for your desired count

```
SELECT cp.payment_ref, COUNT(cp.id) cnt
FROM client_payments AS cp 
WHERE cp.payment_date BETWEEN '2018-05-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-14 23:59:59'
AND cp.`status` = 'Declined'
GROUP BY cp.payment_ref
HAVING cnt >= 3
```

Also do check the [explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) of query and search for keys/indexes are used or not

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the time range is only required within the count subquery.

Why don't you move the where statement into the subquery? This should reduce the runtime drastically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cp.payment_ref) as ref,
 (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM client_payments 
  WHERE status LIKE 'Declined' 
  AND payment_ref = ref
  AND payment_date BETWEEN '2018-05-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-14 23:59:59') as declined 
 FROM client_payments as cp
```

Comment: When you write subquery in select clause it executes N number of times. where N is total rows returned.

Comment: Yep. Distinct still ain't a function.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure you have indices on `payment_ref`, `timestamp` and `status`, I'd tackle it with a self join:

```
SELECT @starttimestamp:='2018-05-14 00:00:00';
SELECT @endtimestamp:='2018-05-14 23:59:59';

SELECT
  first.payment_ref,
  first.timestamp, first.name, first.status,
  second.timestamp, second.name, second.status,
  third.timestamp, third.name, third.status
FROM
  transactions AS first

  -- find a later declined transaction
  INNER JOIN transactions AS second
    ON first.payment_ref=second.payment_ref
    AND first.timestamp<second.timestamp
    AND second.timestamp<=@endtimestamp
    AND second.status LIKE 'Declined%'

  -- find an even later declined transaction
  INNER JOIN transactions AS third
    ON second.payment_ref=third.payment_ref
    AND second.timestamp<third.timestamp
    AND third.timestamp<=@endtimestamp
    AND third.status LIKE 'Declined%'

WHERE first.timestamp BETWEEN @starttimestamp AND @endtimestamp
AND first.status LIKE 'Declined%'
;
```

This makes optimal use of the indices and has a very high selectivity via a key range scans

If you really need the line-by-line form, you can transform it via a wrapper Query, that only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. The quickest running query is as follows at .08 sec

`SELECT cp.payment_ref as ref,count(status='Declined') as no_declined
FROM client_payments as cp
WHERE  cp.payment_date BETWEEN '2018-05-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-14 23:59:59'
GROUP BY cp.payment_ref
HAVING COUNT(status='Declined')>2`